# Rhumb line heading calculation (vbscript)

Tags: vbscript, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to get the heading of the rhumb line from one latitude/longitude to another using vbscript. This is similar to 
[rhumb line calculation - javascript to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541134/rhumb-line-calculation-javascript-to-php)

I'm also trying to convert javascript code from
http://www.yourhomenow.com/house/haversine.html into vbscript.

**Javascript**

```
var dPhi = Math.log(Math.tan(lat2/2+Math.PI/4)/Math.tan(lat1/2+Math.PI/4));
var q = dLat/dPhi;
if (!isFinite(q)) q = Math.cos(lat1.toRad());
// if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb across 180° meridian:
if (Math.abs(dLon) > Math.PI) {
  dLon = dLon>0 ? -(2*Math.PI-dLon) : (2*Math.PI+dLon);
}
var d = Math.sqrt(dLat*dLat + q*q*dLon*dLon) * R; //ignoring this as I don't need distance

var brng =  Math.atan2(dLon, dPhi).toBrng();
```

**My code is as follows**

```
Lat1 = -40.077
Long1 = 150.511
Lat2 = -44.665
Long2 = 167.919

Pi = 3.14159265358979   

dPhi = log(tan(lat2/2+Pi/4)/tan(lat1/2+Pi/4))       
dLat = Lat2-Lat1
dLon = Long2-Long1    

if dLon > Pi then       
  if dLon>0 then
    dLon = -(2*Pi-dLon)
  else
    dLon = (2*Pi+dLon)
  end if    
end if

num = Atan2(dLon, dPhi)
Rhumb = (num*180/Pi)+360 mod 360

Function Atan2(y,x)
Pi = 3.14159265358979
  If x > 0 Then
    Atn2 = Atn(y / x)
  ElseIf x < 0 Then
    Atn2 = Sgn(y) * (Pi - Atn(Abs(y / x)))
  ElseIf y = 0 Then
    Atn2 = 0
  Else
    Atn2 = Sgn(y) * Pi / 2
  End If
End Function
```

My problem comes about from 
    dPhi = log(tan(lat2/2+Pi/4)/tan(lat1/2+Pi/4))

throwing an error as its a log of a negative number.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong, or suggest an alternative? Unfortunately, I have to use classic VBScript for this.

Comment: `Math.log(Math.tan(lat2/2+Math.PI/4)/Math.tan(lat1/2+Math.PI/4))` returns `NaN` for `lat1=-40.077` and `lat2=-44.665`, so the behavior is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. My initial lats and longs were decimals. These needed to be converted to radians first.

```
vLat1 = Lat1 * pi/180 
vLng1 = Long1 * pi/180 
vLat2 = Lat2 * pi/180 
vLng2 = Long2 * pi/180
```

And all subsequent calculations involving lats/longs be done with these new variables